# How to inject a custom Spring PropertySource into Environment in a non-web project?

Tags: spring

I have a custom PropertySource which reads from an external source. I would like to inject that into Spring `Environment` in a non-web and non-spring-boot project.

I think there are ways to do via `ApplicationContextInitializer` but that seems to be specific to a web application as the registration involves setting `contextInitializerClasses`.

My use-case is that the tests in a small project require loading app context and need access to properties set by my custom property source. Mocking those values is not an option and I would like to find if there's a way to register a custom PropertySource with Environment in a non-web project?

Comment: If it is a non web project you have direct access to the `ApplicationContext` and you basically can do anything you want with it. Basically just register the `PropertySource` before calling `refresh` on your `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that should work. Is there a way to automatically register or hook into ApplicationContext? I'm looking for an easier way to do that without programmatic access to application context and without boilerplate.

Comment: Wondering if I could use `ApplicationListener` or `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Any ideas?

Comment: No you cannot as that is too late in the cycle of the context. The `ApplicationContextInitializer` is invented for that and that is what the `ContextLoader` actually uses. You need to modify it before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a Not very elegant way.Regist a component like this.

```java
@Component
public class ZkPropertySourceConfig implements EnvironmentAware, BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        if(environment instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment){
            ConfigurableEnvironment configurableEnvironment = (ConfigurableEnvironment) environment;
            configurableEnvironment.getPropertySources()
                    .addLast(new ZkPropertySource());
        }
    }

    public static class ZkPropertySource extends PropertySource<Void> {

        public ZkPropertySource() {
            super("zk");
        }

        @Override
        public String getProperty(String name) {
            //your code goes here
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explaination of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.